# How to debug TypeError 'str' object is not callable python3 when implementing linkedList

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I'm new to python3. When I run my code against unit testing on my python script, it shows me the following error:
TypeError 'str' object is not callable python3 error output on terminal.
I keep getting this error. TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
I searched all my code and I don't even use the word str anywhere.

Error message shows up at Console. 
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

I used python debugger, and it shows me that the code is giving me an error at when I call function find on line 106. ll.find('A'). After replacing my find function with another snippet below, it does not throw that TypeError anymore. I was wondering if anyone can help me out with my implementation. 
I include my original code here.

```
#!python

#from __future__ import print_function


class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        """Initialize this node with the given data"""
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return a string representation of this node"""
        return 'Node({})'.format(repr(self.data))


class LinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        """Initialize this linked list; append the given items, if any"""
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.nodeCount = 0
        if iterable:
            for item in iterable:
                self.append(item)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return a string representation of this linked list"""
        return 'LinkedList({})'.format(repr(self.items()))

    def items(self):
        """Return a list of all items in this linked list"""
        result = []
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            result.append(current.data)
            # result.append(current)
            current = current.next
        return result

    def is_empty(self):
        """Return True if this linked list is empty, or False"""
        return self.head is None

    def length(self):
        """Return the length of this linked list by traversing its nodes"""
        return self.nodeCount

    def append(self, item):
        """Insert the given item at the tail of this linked list"""
        new_node = Node(item)
        self.nodeCount += 1

        if self.tail == None and self.head == None:
            self.tail = new_node
            self.head = new_node
        elif self.tail == self.head:
            self.tail = new_node
            self.head.next = new_node
        else:
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node

    def prepend(self, item):
        """Insert the given item at the head of this linked list"""
        new_node = Node(item)

        # if self.is_empty():
        #     self.tail = new_node
        #     self.head = new_node

        if self.head == None and self.tail == None:
            self.tail = new_node
            self.head = new_node
        elif self.head == self.tail:
            self.head = new_node
            self.head.next = self.tail
        else:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node

    def find(self, quality):
        """Return an item from this linked list satisfying the given quality"""
        for item in self.items():
            if quality(item):
                return item

    def replace(self, quality, new_data):
        """replace an item from this linked list satisfying the given quality"""
        current = self.head

        while current is not None:
            if quality(current.data):
                return
            current = current.next
        self.append(new_data)

def test_linked_list():
    ll = LinkedList()
    print(ll)
    ll.append('A')
    print(ll)
    ll.append('B')
    print(ll)
    ll.append('C')
    print(ll)
    print('head: ' + str(ll.head))
    print('tail: ' + str(ll.tail))
    print('length: ' + str(ll.length()))
    print(ll.length())

    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    ll.delete('A')
    print(ll)
    ll.delete('C')
    print(ll)
    ll.delete('B')
    print(ll)
    print('head: ' + str(ll.head))
    print('tail: ' + str(ll.tail))
    print('length: ' + str(ll.length()))
    print(ll.length())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_linked_list()
```

I was able to get my code not to throw TypeError with the following code:

```
#!python

#from __future__ import print_function


class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        """Initialize this node with the given data"""
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        self.previous = None

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return a string representation of this node"""
        return 'Node({})'.format(repr(self.data))


class LinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        """Initialize this linked list; append the given items, if any"""
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.nodeCount = 0
        if iterable:
            for item in iterable:
                self.append(item)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return a string representation of this linked list"""
        return 'LinkedList({})'.format(repr(self.items()))

    def items(self):
        """Return a list of all items in this linked list"""
        result = []
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            result.append(current.data)
            # result.append(current)
            current = current.next
        return result

    def is_empty(self):
        """Return True if this linked list is empty, or False"""
        return self.head is None

    def length(self):
        """Return the length of this linked list by traversing its nodes"""
        return self.nodeCount

    def append(self, item):
        """Insert the given item at the tail of this linked list"""
        new_node = Node(item)
        self.nodeCount += 1

        if self.tail == None and self.head == None:
            self.tail = new_node
            self.head = new_node
        elif self.tail == self.head:
            self.tail = new_node
            self.head.next = new_node
        else:
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node

    def prepend(self, item):
        """Insert the given item at the head of this linked list"""
        new_node = Node(item)

        # if self.is_empty():
        #     self.tail = new_node
        #     self.head = new_node

        if self.head == None and self.tail == None:
            self.tail = new_node
            self.head = new_node
        elif self.head == self.tail:
            self.head = new_node
            self.head.next = self.tail
        else:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node

    def delete(self, item):
        """Delete the given item from this linked list, or raise ValueError"""
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current is not None:
            if current.data == item:
                if current is not self.head and current is not self.tail:
                    previous.next = current.next
                    current.next = None
                    break
                if current is self.head:
                    self.head = current.next
                    current.next = None
                if current is self.tail:
                    if previous is not None:
                        previous.next = None
                    self.tail = previous
                return
            previous = current
            current = current.next
        raise ValueError('Item not found: {}'.format(item))


    def find(self, quality):
        """Return an item from this linked list satisfying the given quality"""
        for item in self.items():
            if quality(item):
                return item

    def replace(self, quality, new_data):
        """replace an item from this linked list satisfying the given quality"""
        current = self.head

        while current is not None:
            if quality(current.data):
                return
            current = current.next
        self.append(new_data)


    def replace(self, item, new_item):
        """replace an item with new_item by using the helper function finding the item"""
        node = self.find_node(item)
        node.data = new_item

    def find_node(self, item):
        """Returns the first node it encounters where data is equal to item"""
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node is not None:
            if current_node.data == item:
                return current_node
            current_node = current_node.next

def test_linked_list():
    ll = LinkedList()
    print(ll)
    ll.append('A')
    print(ll)
    ll.append('B')
    print(ll)
    ll.append('C')
    print(ll)
    print('head: ' + str(ll.head))
    print('tail: ' + str(ll.tail))
    print(ll.length())

    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    ll.delete('A')
    print(ll)
    ll.delete('C')
    print(ll)
    ll.delete('B')
    print(ll)
    print('head: ' + str(ll.head))
    print('tail: ' + str(ll.tail))
    print(ll.length())

    ll.append('A')
    print(ll)
    ll.append('B')
    print(ll)
    ll.append('C')
    print(ll)
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    ll.find_node('A')
    print("___________________")
    ll.replace('B', 'A')
    ll.replace('A', 'M')
    print(ll)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_linked_list()
```

output of the code:

```
LinkedList([])
LinkedList(['A'])
LinkedList(['A', 'B'])
LinkedList(['A', 'B', 'C'])
head: Node('A')
tail: Node('C')
3
LinkedList(['B', 'C'])
LinkedList(['B'])
LinkedList([])
head: None
tail: None
3
LinkedList(['A'])
LinkedList(['A', 'B'])
LinkedList(['A', 'B', 'C'])
> linkedlist.py(170)test_linked_list()
-> ll.find_node('A')
(Pdb) c
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Start by formatting your code properly

Comment: it's correctly format and I just test it on my console

Comment: `str` is just the class of any string object. `type('A')` is `str`

Comment: You can simulate the same error by doing something like `x = 'A'; x()`. Does that look like something you are doing on line 106?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. It is very difficult to trace your exception without one.